# APIKitでiTunesAPIから楽曲情報を取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, json

APIKitでiTunesAPIで楽曲情報を取得してRealmに保存したいのですが，
以下のコードで出力したobjectがAny型で

```
{
    resultCount = 10;
    results =     (
                {
            artistId = 298496035;
            artistName = "\U30a2\U30f4\U30a3\U30fc\U30c1\U30fc";
            artistViewUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jp/artist/avu-ichi/id298496035?uo=4";
            artworkUrl100 = "http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music4/v4/0e/c9/c8/0ec9c862-abdd-8827-9b0d-c30443a88e86/source/100x100bb.jpg";
・・・（以下略）
```

となっており，要素を取り出すことができません．
ご教授お願いします．

```
import APIKit

protocol iTunesRequest: Request {
}

extension iTunesRequest {
    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com")!
    }
}

struct GetSearchRequest: iTunesRequest {
    typealias Response = [Song]    
    var method: HTTPMethod {
    return .get
    }
    let term: String
    init(term: String) {
        self.term = term
    }

    var path: String {
        return "/search"
    }

    var parameters: Any? {
        return [
            "term": term,
            "limit": 10,
            "country": "jp",
            "media": "music",
            "lang": "ja_jp"
        ]
    }

   func response(from object: Any, urlResponse: HTTPURLResponse) throws -> Response {
        var Songs = [Song]()

        print(object)

        if let dictionaries = object as? [NSDictionary] {
            print(dictionaries)
            for dictionary in dictionaries {
                print(dictionary)
                let song = Song()
                song.itunesId = dictionary["trackId"] as! Int
                song.title = dictionary["trackName"] as! String
                song.artwork = dictionary["artworkUrl100"] as! String
                song.artist = dictionary["artistName"] as! String
                song.album = dictionary["collectionName"] as! String
                song.trackSource = dictionary["previewUrl"] as! String
                Songs.append(song)
            }
        }
        return Songs
    }
}
```

Comment: APIKitなるものは見たことも使ったこともないのでその部分は全くわからないのですが、iOSの場合JSONとして送られてきた来たデータは(通常、内部的には)NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, NSNumber, NSNullに変換されます。(JSONのテキスト表現を文字列として持っていても処理に困るだけでしょう。)あなたの表示された内容はNSDictionaryの文字列表現ですから、正しく読み込めていると言うことになります。print出力の見た目が「JSONではありません」なんてことは忘れて、本当は何がしたいのか、何がうまくいかないのかをお知らせください。

Comment: 質問の趣旨が分かりづらく申し訳ありません．編集させていただきました．objectはAny型でどうやってその要素（例えばartistName）を抽出すれば良いのか分かりません．さらに今の場合はartistNameをエンコード(?)する必要もありそうですがその方法もわかりません．

Comment: 確認ですが、現在掲載されたコードで`print(object)`した結果が掲載の内容(`print(dictionary)`ではなく)ということでよろしいでしょうか?